# Prove there is a path of length 6

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that if $G$ is a planar bipartite graph and each vertex has degree at least 3, then $G$ contains a path of length $6$.

Since the graph is planar and bipartite

$\sum_{v \in G} deg(v) = 2e$ where $e$ is # of edges.

Now suppose $P = v_0v_1v_2v_3v_4v_5$ is the longest path and has length 5 (for sake of contradiction).

However since $v_5$ has degree at least $3$ it must have 2 more neighbors in $P$

But at this point I am getting stuck. Any tips?

Comment: I have a black-out in imagining such a graph, but you want at this point to show, that $v_0$ and $v_2$ could not be $v_5$'s neighbors simultaneously (I've already used bipartite to dissect sides), and it should probably somehow come from planar part, i.e. some edge would intersect some other edge (I suppose try to draw them in columns, to get the idea)

Comment: And path of length 5 you have by just using "degree at least 3 + bipartite".

Comment: What is your definition for path?

Comment: Isn't $\sum d_i = 2e$ true for any graph?

Answer (score 1):

Try drawing a bipartite planar graph in which every vertex has degree at least three. In a bipartite graph, the vertices can be colored with two colors, red and blue. So the graph has to have at least one red vertex, $a_1$, with three blue neighbors, $b_1, b_2, b_3$. Now $b_1$ needs two extra red neighbors, $a_2$ and $a_3$... If you try to continue this construction, you'll find that if you're not careful, you end up drawing $K_{3,3}$. If you avoid that, then you'll end up with a path of length $5$.

So now you've proven that a graph satisfying your conditions must have a path of length $5$. Now zoom in on that path, say $v_1v_2v_3v_4v_5$. All you need to do is prove that $v_5$ (or $v_6$) has an extra neighbor somewhere. You can do this using only bipartness and the degree condition, you don't need planarity anymore.

Comment: For the last part what is the argument about the neighbor? I know that $v_5$ will be need 2 more neighbors in the path. But the path you have drawn $v_1v_2v_3v_4v_5$ is only length $4$ not $5$?

Comment: @asdfghjk The argument is that the only other neighbor $v_5$ can have would be $v_2$, so it needs an extra one that isn't already on the path. I thought "length" referred to the number of vertices, but I think if you now look at $v_1...v_6$, you can show (using planarity this time) that there must be a path of length $6$. Now that I know what the actual definition of "length" is, I'm trying to see if I can find a more elegant argument...

Answer (score 1):

(We need to assume there is a vertex; it's false for the empty graph.)

Since there are no degree-$1$ vertices, the graph contains a cycle $C_k$.  Moreover, the cycle has length in $\{4,6,8,\ldots\}$, since the graph is bipartite.  If $k \geq 8$, then this cycle contains a $6$-edge path.

If $k=6$, then since this $C_6$ does not induce a complete bipartite $K_{3,3}$ subgraph (since the graph is planar), some vertex in it is adjacent to a vertex outside the $C_6$:

[image]

This subgraph contains a $6$-edge path.

If $k=4$, then we consider neighbors of the $4$-cycle belonging to a subgraph depicted below:

[image]

If $x$ and $y$ are adjacent, then we have a $C_6$ subgraph, which is the $k=6$ case.

If $x$ and $y$ are not adjacent, then $x$ is adjacent to a non-depicted vertex (since it has degree $\geq 3$), which gives a $6$-edge path.